# How to retrieve file from Virtual Machine on Mac?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu using Sun VirtualBox on my Mac OSX and I badly need some UMLs from it.

How do I go about retrieving the files, without using a USB (cannot find one)?

Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I was able to get file transfers working on Virtual Box. Only 3 steps ([original VirtualBox documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders)):

1. PRE-REQUISITE: Make sure you **install "Guest additions"** on your guest VM. (Google "how do you install guest additions")
2. In the host goto the GUI window with the running guest VM. Goto the GUI menubar --> Devices --> Shared drive --> click on "Add Share" --> **Choose a folder on the host file system** that you would like the guest to see --> give a human readable name.

   - The human readable name is used in step 3 so make sure to keep it simple. I suggest no spaces, no symbols.
3. [If $VirtualBoxVersion < 4.0] In the guest, **run the mount command**.

   - If $VirtualBoxVersion > 4.0 then the mounting is done automatically.

---

Here is the syntax for the mount command:

```
mount -t vboxsf $SHARENAME $MOUNTPOINT
```

- NOTE: The '`-t vboxsf`' specifies that you are mounting a special "virtual box shared folder" (The mount command runs a script for this special "type". The script is installed when you install guest additions.)
- SHARENAME = The name you gave the folder in step 2.
- MOUNTPOINT = The location on the guest file system that you want the shared folder to be mounted at. For a Linux Guest, the suggested mounting location is: /media/$LOCATION.

---

EXAMPLE Mount command that worked for me:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf tmp /media/host/tmp
```

NOTE: Before you can use this same location. You have to make sure the folder already is created by doing '`mkdir -p /media/host/tmp`'